# How are Distributed Snapshot algorithms (likes of Chandy Lamport) implemented in real world Distributed systems?

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, snapshot

Can anyone explain, how Distributed Snapshot algorithms ( Example: [Chandy-Lamport](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/chandy.pdf) are implemented in the context of modern distributed systems?

Can you name an open source System implementation which uses this / these class of algorithm?

How does this theory really translate to real world?

Comment: Can anyone explain why I am being downvoted? I posted the question on cs.stackexchange.com and was told by mods to repost on stackoverflow: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30246/how-are-distributed-snapshot-algorithms-likes-of-chandy-lamport-implemented-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be useful for rollback recovery systems on network-on-chip (NOC) systems.It is also used for determining the global state of the system during computation.

As an example HP uses this kind of algorithms for rollback-recovery protocol for crash/recover
hosts and fair-loss links. you can find an interesting article about that here:

http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2010/HPL-2010-155.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Believe it or not, while I was struggling through this question, I sent an email to [Dr. Jeff Dean](http://research.google.com/people/jeff/) with this question and he did send me a reply! :-)

Here is his answer to the question and I quote :

"Our Spanner system is a distributed system that provides snapshot read isolation, which might be one practical example of snapshotting algorithms:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/archive/spanner-osdi2012.pdf"

Answer (score 2):

Apache Flink makes use of a distributed snapshot algorithm (for checkpointing) very similar to the Chandy Lamport. A marker is sent across the network that signals to the nodes they need to record their state with the slight difference that the state of the channels is not recorded.

The following two papers contain more information on this:

- Lightweight  Asynchronous  Snapshots  for  Distributed  Dataflows ([link](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:827567/FULLTEXT01.pdf))
- State Management in Apache Flink ([link](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol10/p1718-carbone.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

One of the application is knowing the "Stable Property" which is defined as a property which if present in the global state will remain so until there is an external intervention(outside our distributed system).A major example can be: "State of termination". Let's say you are running heavy computations which are split among your distributed systems. You can know the termination state if you take snapshot twice and compare and find the local state of the channel, as well as the systems/processes, are same.